# Whitelist Azure Automation account in Azure Storage to read zipped module from blob and upload in azure automation module

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-automation

I have uploaded the zipped powershell module in Azure Blob Storage and my networking is selected as  Allow access from Selected networks. I am running below command to upload module in azure automation-

`New-AzAutomationModule -ResourceGroupName $automationrg -AutomationAccountName $automationaccount -Name ($Mod.Name).Replace('.zip','') -ContentLink $Blob.ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri`

After running this command, I am getting below error.

[error]{"Message":"Module is not accessible. Exception: This request is not authorized to perform this operation."}
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

I checked and get to know that it is a firewall issue and I can not select access from all virtual networks. How Can I whitelist azure automation in storage networking?

Answer (score 1):

> I checked and get to know that it is a firewall issue and I can not select access from all virtual networks. How Can I whitelist azure automation in storage networking?

Whitelisting all Automation account's IP address is not option because it is impossible to keep up with updates hundreds of IP-addresses.

In this Case, you can use Azure Private Link to connect networks to Azure Automation. But this has the main limitation:

> > Private Link support with Azure Automation is available only in Azure Commercial and Azure US Government clouds.

One option which might work for you is to use a [Hybrid Worker Group in Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-windows-hrw-install#automated-deployment). The systems can be your physical systems that can reach Azure or your Azure VMs. You can then grant access to the IP addresses that are in your Hybrid Runbook Worker group.

**References:**

1. [Use Azure Private Link to securely connect networks to Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/how-to/private-link-security)
2. [Azure Automation network configuration details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-network-configuration)
3. [Access storage account with Automation Account / Runbook - MSFT Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/127460/access-storage-account-with-automatio-account-runb.html)